# what is the difference between $P(H)+P(T)=1$ and $P(\{H\})+P(\{T\})=1$?

Tags: probability

both following 2 equations are to indicate that the probability of either heads or tails, is 1.

$P(H)+P(T)=1$

$P(\{H\})+P(\{T\})=1$

the second one comes from [wiki Probability_axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Simple_example:_coin_toss)

what is the difference between these 2 notations?

is the measure theoretical perspective the only difference?

Comment: It's just a matter of whether one uses $H$ to denote the event of flipping heads, or uses $H$ to denote the outcome of flipping heads, and then letting $\{H\}$ denoting the event consisting of this single outcome. People are often loose with this type of notation, and I would not spend too much time stressing out over it.

Comment: They are just different ways to refer to probabilities on subsets of the two element sample space $\{H,T\}$. In a very formal setting the second might be preferable, but it's annoying to type and to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{H\}$ and $\{T\}$ are subsets of the two-element event space $\{H,T\}$ and so $P(\{H\})$ refers to the probability that the outcome is $\{H\}\subseteq\{H,T\}$ and $P(\{T\})$ refers to the probability that the outcome is $\{T\}\subseteq \{H,T\}.$ From a set-theoretic point of view, you could also note that since $P(\{H\})$ and $P(\{T\})$ are independent, $P(\{H\})+P(\{T\}) = P(\{H\}\cup\{T\}) = P(\{H,T\})=1.$

P({H}) is simply a more formal way of writing P(H), as pointed out in the comments to your question

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Given "$P(\{H\})$ refers to the probability that the outcome is $\{H\}\subseteq\{H,T\}$", what does $P(H)$ mean?

Comment: P({H}) is simply a more formal way of writing P(H), as pointed out in the comments to your question

Answer (score 0):

the notation is ambiguous. is a functional notation but incorporates the result in the argument of the function.

P(H) represents the probability to obtain heads after one coin toss.

P({H}) represents the function that models the probability to obtain heads after any coin toss in a series of coin toss.

P(H)+P(T)=1 means that the chance of getting heads or tail is 1 during the same event of a coin toss.
P({H})+P({T})=1 means that the chance of getting heads on current toss or tail on any other toss past, current or future is still 1. This sentence is false.